# Kube CSS grid not responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, kube-css

I am using the [Kube CSS framework](http://imperavi.com/kube/) and am having troubles with the responsive grid.

I have html like this, which was taken from the first example [here](http://imperavi.com/kube/css/grid/)

```
<body>

  <div class="units-row">
      <div class="unit-50">Hello world</div>
      <div class="unit-50">It's Kube Grid System</div>
  </div>

  <style>
    .unit-50 {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
      padding: 2em;
    }
  </style>

</body>
```

The page renderers the same in the example on desktop

[image: page on desktop]

The problem is when I am on mobile. When I open chrome dev tools on the Kube grid examples, the columns are responsive and get width 100%.

[image: kube responsive]

This is what my page looks like on mobile

[image: my mobile]

It appears like my screen width is >900px when it is 375px on Kubes grid example. I do not have any external css being loaded that would modify this.

I know my site is still responsive because when I resize the browser window the columns do get width 100%.

[image: responsive mine]

For some reason on mobile my screen width is much higher than on the Kube CSS website. Do I need to do anything to make my page behave this way?

This is really confusing me as it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after hours of googling (mind you probably just a few minutes of searching for the right thing), putting this meta tag in the head of the document

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

will make the grid responsive on mobile

Comment: FYI, this is stated in their Quick Start guide: https://imperavi.com/kube/docs/quick-start/